# Creating a new dataframe with restrictions in wine dataset

Tags: r

From the dataset wine.csv. I want to Create a new dataframe called Wine_A, where the only data is Type “A” AND Magnesium > 100. (type and magnesium are two variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *subset* the wine data frame as follows:

```
wine_new <- wine[wine$Type == 'A' & wine$Magnesium > 100, ]
```

Comment: also  how to Aggregate/summarize the data of the average of alcohol and proline BY type (you should get a table) ?

Comment: No, I won't answer that question.  Stack Overflow doesn't work this way.  It is not a free homework service.

Comment: Appreciate your help